# Bizarre python syntax error with loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a problem with loading a data file in python. The error that I'm getting is

```
datasim = loadtxt("/home/ddrek/Dust/ppc/1925.txt")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

data = loadtxt("/home/di/DI/ic/da/flash/oux.19_"+str(DOM))
d, t, q = data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,3]                         
d, t, q = loadtxt("/home/di/DI/ic/da/flash/oux.19_"+str(DOM), usecols = #(1,2,3),      unpack=True)

datasim = loadtxt("/home/ddrek/Dust/ppc/1925.txt")
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you see a mysterious syntax error like that, the problem is usually in the previous line.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `#` character from:

```
d, t, q = loadtxt("/home/di/DI/ic/da/flash/oux.19_"+str(DOM), usecols = #(1,2,3),      unpack=True)
```

because `#` is used to make comments in Python.

You may also want to edit your code if it is required.